# Where is Laravel's core?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I understand [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework) is Laravel's core, but when you want to create a Laravel application you need download [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel), create a project via composer, or whatever.

This question might be stupid, but, where is the actual core in a Laravel project? Meaning that I can't browse through the application's folder to find it, whereas I am pretty sure I could do it in other frameworks such as CodeIgniter, `core` folder maybe?.

So where is the kernel? How is all linked so that the application works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `composer install`, it downloads it to this directory:

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate

Comment: oh, then I must be blind.